# How to read user's account e-mail in Windows 10 universal app?

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I need to read primary account e-mail address in Windows 10 universal app?

Comment: apps run in sandbox so you will not have access to that info

Comment: Android apps run in sandbox too but they have an option to read the profile e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [UserDataAccountManager Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserDataAccountManager).

And in order to gain access to the UserDataAccountStore, your app must declare at least one of the following capabilities:

1. contacts
2. appointments
3. email

Refer to [UserDataAccountManager class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.userdataaccounts.userdataaccountmanager) for more details.